# Is there some way I could combine this C# code?

Tags: c#

I have the following code. It looks to me like there is a way I could combine it into one statement but I am not sure how to do this.

```
List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();

var emptyItem = new SelectListItem(){
    Value = "",
    Text  = "00"
};

items.Add(emptyItem);

ViewBag.AccountIdList = new SelectList(items);
```

Can someone tell me if it's possible to simplify this.

Thanks,

Comment: It does depend on your C# / .net version iirc. Not really sure when collection and object initializers where added...

Comment: Well, since he's using an object initializer in his code above, it's probably safe to assume he's good there.

Comment: @JamesMichaelHare: yes, very true remark ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can use the collection and object initializers together to create the item, add it to the list, and wrap the list all in one statement.

```
ViewBag.AccountIdList = new SelectList(
    new List<SelectListItem>
    {
         new SelectListItem
         {
            Value = "",
            Text = "00"
         }
    });
```

The indentation style above is how I prefer to type it with all the curlies on their own line, but you could even one-line it if you wanted.

Either way it's a single statement.

And incidentally, since you are just passing the `List<SelectListItem>` to a `SelectList` constructor, which takes an `IEnumerable`, you could just pass an array of 1 instead of a list for a bit more performance:

```
ViewBag.AccountIdList = new SelectList(
    new []
    {
         new SelectListItem
         {
            Value = "",
            Text = "00"
         }
    });
```

Both would work the same in this case, the latter is a bit more efficient, but both are fine and it's up to you which you prefer.  For more info I did a short blog entry comparing different ways to return a [single item as an `IEnumerable<T>` sequence](http://blackrabbitcoder.net/archive/2011/12/08/c-fundamentals-returning-zero-or-one-item-as-ienumerablelttgt.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

```
ViewBag.AccountIdList = new SelectList(new List<SelectListItem> { new SelectListItem { Value = "", Text = "00"} });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var items = new List<SelectListItem>()
{
   new SelectListItem { Value = "", Text = "00" }
}

ViewBag.AccountIdList = new SelectList(items);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would be the closest you could get it to.

```
List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();
items.Add(new SelectListItem(){
    Value = "",
    Text  = "00"
});
ViewBag.AccountIdList = new SelectList(items);
```

Answer (score 0):

Less <strike>readable</strike> testable, IMO ...but you can write:

```
items.Add(new SelectedListItem(){
    Value = "",
    Text  = "00"
});
```

I wouldn't recommend more than this in a single statement. This statement can also be refactored into a method accepting parameters for `Value` and `Text`:

```
// now this is a unit testable method
SelectedListItem CreateSelectedItem (string value, string text) {
   return new SelectedListItem(){
        Value = value,
        Text  = text
    };
}
```

Now you can write the following which is very clear in what it does while being concise:

```
ViewBag.AccountIdList = new SelectList(items.Add(CreateSelectedItem("someValue", "someText"));
```

Answer (score 0):

ViewBag.AccountIdList = new SelectList(List items = new List { new SelectListItem{Value="",Text="00"}});

Answer (score 0):

```
ViewBag.AccountIdList = new List<SelectListItem>{new SelectListItem{Value = "", Text  = "00"}};
```